# Why is this question protected although it doesn't have an answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, protected-questions

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874684/parse-json-data-and-get-image-in-android) is protected by Community. Why is this question protected? What's so special about it? The question doesn't have an accepted answer and really doesn't have a useful answer, so what is the reason behind protecting this question?

Comment: It received several low-quality non-answers that were deleted, qualifying it for automatic protection.

Comment: "that was my pronlem too any answer?"  Programmer pron.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question

Answer (score 23):

Questions are protected automatically when they receive a number of low-quality posts that need to be deleted.

In this case, there are 3 deleted posts; one asking another, new question, and two posts asking if the problem has been solved yet. To avoid the question from attracting further such non-answers (which create work for our community having to clean them up again), automatic protection kicks in.

Protection has little to do with wether or not the question has an accepted solution. Of course, hard problems that many new users encounter have a higher chance of attracting *did you solve it yet* posts from users that cannot comment yet.

Comment: There are actually *five* deleted responses.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: two more were deleted after I posted this answer, one by the answer owner, the other by the community.